# Qt/MAC: Build machine 10.5, Client machine 10.7

Tags: qt

I'm building a QT (4.7.4) MacOSX application on a 10.5 build machine. The application should run on 10.5, 10.6 and 10.7

My symptoms are: the app runs nicely on the 10.5 machine it was built on but will not even launch on 10.7, not even as much as an error message. The system logs however show:

```
Feb 14 11:55:12 Ron-MAC com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[139] ([0x0-0x502502].com.MyCompany.MyApp[40719]): posix_spawn("/Users/user/Desktop/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp", ...): Permission denied
Feb 14 11:55:12 Ron-MAC com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[139] ([0x0-0x502502].com.MyCompany.MyApp[40719]): Exited with code: 1
Feb 14 11:55:22 Ron-MAC bootpd[102]: service time 0.000011 seconds
```

One of my guesses is that the build machine uses 10.5 SDK which does not exist on 10.7. I need therefore to build my project with SDK 10.6 - how can I configure my .Pro file to use a base SDK 10.6 so that an app built on a 10.5 machine can run on 10.5, 10.6 and 10.7?

Comment: Did you run macdeployqt described here? http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-mac.html#the-mac-deployment-tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by applying:

```
chmod a+x
```

to the app bundle, as well as the executable inside the app bundle.

Go figure.